# Fast reading of numerical matrices from file in R

Tags: r, matrix

Frequently I encounter large matrices intended for R processing which have N column names in the first row, while all the other rows have N+1 separated values, the first being the row name. The separator could be "," or "\t". All the values are floats apart from column and row names.

These files are easily read with read.table() but they take tens of minutes for files of 4.5K columns and 220K rows. I tried the "readr" package but it doesn't support row names, and it complains that there are excess columns in all the rows.

Are there any available optimizations that would work in this case? Is there a package that supports this naturally, or a solution with common options?

Comment: try using `fread()` from package `data.table`. I am not sure if it can read the row names off the top of my head. What you can do is `skip = 1` to skip the first row and read it in. Then you can separately do `nrows = 1` to read in the column names. From there you can do some rearranging. as you need.

Comment: @Adam I considered that beforehand, but I read in the documentation: "Dates are read as character currently. They can be converted afterwards using the excellent fasttime package or standard base functions."
I assumed that something directly aware of numerical values would be faster, by taking congruent memory locations or other. Do you think this is worth exploring?

Comment: Oh, are the row names dates? I think it should still be fast. In my experience `fread` flies. There are also other ways to save files from R which can be very fast. But that assumes they originated from R to begin with. If you are stuck with a tab or comma separated, then I think `fread` might be your best bet.

Comment: I agree @Adam, `fread()` is extremely fast and should suit your purpose well. To my experience, converting dates afterward using `fasttime` is also pretty fast.

Comment: Sorry guys, I read datas, not dates, and thought this meant something completely different. Actually I don't have dates at all. Please answer the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fread` from `data.table`. It will assume that the first column contains row names and add an extract column for you named `V1`. Then you can just rearrange a bit.

```
library(data.table)

write.table(mtcars, "test.txt")
data <- fread("test.txt", data.table = FALSE)
```

Assign rownames and drop column.

```
rownames(data) <- data[,1]
data <- data[, -1]
```